# UIGestureRecognizer or transparent Button for tappable label?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I need to segue to another view when the user taps either of the information labels shown in the image below (above the colored riser bars):

[image]

It looks like I can implement such a solution using the label itself. However, it seems a little convoluted, and since I'm pretty green I avoid convolution anytime I can.

But while I have no experience with `UIGestureRecognizer`, I am reasonably comfortable with buttons. Would it be a breach of best practice to just place a button with a transparent background (indicated here by the black rectangle) on top of the label in question?

Comment: why not just replace the label with a button?

Comment: I considered doing that but wasn't sure if UIButton had the same text handling capabilities as UILabel. You can see there are three lines of text. Would that be a problem?

Comment: if you'd check the documentation, you would realize that a button uses a label to display text. does that answer the question?

Comment: It probably won't cause too many problems to use your button method, but I suggest learning and becoming comfortable with gestureRecognizers.  They are extremely easy if you're already comfortable with buttons.  A button is a new set of views that has a gesture recognizer on it.  You'd be adding a lot of stuff you don't need.  Probably not the worst performance wise, but you might as well start learning gestureRecognizers now. You're gonna use them, I promise.

Comment: It is obvious that OP also need to learn about buttons too.

Comment: You're quite right, @vikingosegundo. And that's why I'm here--to learn. Very much appreciated, and I'll dig more deeply into the docs on buttons. So, your advice, generally, would be to use a button anytime you need to interact with a view that displays changeable text in preference to using a label and UIGestureRecognizers?

Comment: @vikingosegundo--Your comment was succinct and constructive. If you'd care to formalize it as an answer, it'll be my pleasure to upvote and accept.

Comment: my advice: if the functionality is those of a button, use a button. Use tap gesture recognizer for more complex situations or if you are prodded with an label and can't change that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. In this case, the label seemed appropriate at first because the need for user interaction wasn't anticipated. Very helpful, upvoted and accepted--see below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do neither. Instead replace the label with an UIButton. As [buttons use labels](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW40) to display it's text, you can achieve the same look without having to deal with transparent buttons or extra objects like the gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have two choices :
Create an UItapgesture recognizer for each UIlabel or add UIButton with background transparent but I think the best way it's to create UItapGestureRecognizer for each UIlabel

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(respondToTapGesture:)];

[yourLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Of course implement the selector respondToTapGesture.

Comment: vikingosegundo offered an elegant solution that, if I'd had a little more experience, I'd like to think I'd have thought of myself. See accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. When I read the subject and your explanation. I give you the code to become better with UITapGestureRecognizer.